# convert numbers decimal c#

Tags: c#, numbers

I have a problem in converting numbers.

I have :

```
private decimal amount { get; set; }
```

When I write in a textbox the value `10.15`, the conversion is good, it converts me to `10,15`

But when I write `10` or `35` it's not `10,00` or `35,00` but the value it's the same `10` and `35`

How can I convert it ?

Thanks

Comment: You're looking at string representations, it really doesn't matter if the variable has the 0's or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using String Format to show decimal upto 2 places or simple integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-upto-2-places-or-simple-integer)

Comment: `Decimal.Parse()` method?

Comment: what  you try update code

Comment: Show where you convert the textbox.text to decimal

Comment: Related: [Preventing double.Parse from removing trailing zeros after decimal place?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4415596/1324033)

Comment: I cannot show you the textbox cause it's a special textbox in a framework (Textbox.UIDecimal) so it converts everything but not the numbers like 10, 35, 85, 135...

Answer (score 2):

A `decimal` is just a number - it doesn't have a format.

You specify the format of a number when you *display* (or parse) it - if you're just looking at the value in the debugger, implicitly casting to string (e.g. setting the `.Text` property of a control), or calling `.ToString` without specifying a format, then you're implicitly using the default format of the system (including any cultural specifics).  For `decimal` that default format is `G` (General), which shows the number in the most compact form possible.  So if there is no fractional part to the decimal value, no decimal places are shown.

If you want to specify a particular format when you display the string, then use either `string.Format` or `.ToString`

```
txtValue.Text = amount.ToString("N2");
```

or use any [custom formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) you desire.

Note that some UI controls (perhaps including your `TextBox.UIDecimal`) have a "Format" property to specify the format that is used when the value is displayed.  In that case, you can set the format to `N2` in the designer or in code-behind.

Comment: It's ok but when I write 100 it's 10,00